# averages for select columns for each row in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy data matrix called `values` of 9000 rows by 49 columns. 
I want to calculate the average of the first 14 columns for each row and output that as an array with the same number of rows (i.e. 9000, same as `len(values)`).

```
import numpy

av15=[]
a = int()
for i in range(len(values)):
    for x in range(0,14):
    a += values[i,x]
b = a/14
av15.append(b)

av15 = numpy.array(av15)
av15 = av15.reshape([len(values),1])    
numpy.savetxt("av15.txt",av15, delimiter = "\t")
```

My code calculates only the average correctly for the first row, from there on the values are not correct. I can't find what is wrong, but there must be some logical mistake that I can't seem to find.. Can anyone find it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your original function is that you are not resetting the accumulator `a` between iterations. Reusing your syntax you could do:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    a = int()
    for x in range(0, 14):
        a += values[i, x]
```

Or since Python is not a strongly typed language, use the much clearer:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    a = 0
    for x in range(0, 14):
        a += values[i, x]
```

Either way, the proper numpy construct for what you are after is this simple and efficient one-liner:

```
av15 = np.mean(values[:, :14]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Jaime! Can I ask: what does the exclamation mark mean in `,:!4`  ?

Comment: It means that I can't type: should be `14`, have edited the post.

Answer (score -1):

I used the alternative below, and it gives me all the right numbers, but I still don't understand why the more archaic solution in my question would only work for the first row.

```
av15=[]
a = int()
for i in range(len(values)):
    a = values[i,0:14].mean()
    av15.append(a)

av15 = numpy.array(av15)
av15 = av15.reshape([len(values),1])    
numpy.savetxt("av15.txt",av15, delimiter = "\t")
```

Comment: Perhaps you should amend your question (if appropriate) or add bounty instead of re-asking your same question in the form of an answer.

Comment: I see you have missing indent for `a += values[i,x]` however I hazard a guess that it is just copy pasta because I would expect the code you pasted to fail due to empty loop block `for x in range(0,14):`